# TypeError: 'RobertaTokenizer' object is not callable

Tags: python, huggingface-tokenizers

I followed documentation on [RoBERTa](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/roberta.html). and ran the following code segment:

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
tokenizer("Hello world")['input_ids']
tokenizer(" Hello world")['input_ids']
```

Then I got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-b70f7dbb4c6e> in <module>
      1 from transformers import RobertaTokenizer
      2 tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
----> 3 tokenizer("Hello world")['input_ids']
      4 tokenizer(" Hello world")['input_ids']

TypeError: 'RobertaTokenizer' object is not callable
```

I found a [fix suggestion](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5580) that says that we need to install transformers version > 3.0.0. Then the installation log looks like:

```
allennlp 1.0.0 requires transformers<2.12,>=2.9, but you'll have transformers 3.1.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed tokenizers-0.8.1rc2 transformers-3.1.0
```

But the we still getting the same error of 'RobertaTokenizer' object is not callable.